# TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined in ElectronJS application

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, axios

I'm using `axios` and `fs` to download an image to the local directory. I'm using ElectronJS and VueJS to create a desktop application.

```
async saveOptions() {

      var currentLightbox = this.currentLightbox
      var title = currentLightbox.data.title.replace(/\s/g, '_')
      console.log(title)



      var URL = currentLightbox.data.preview.images[0].source.url
      fs.mkdir('images/', {recursive: true}, (err) => {
        if (err) throw(err)
      })
      const Path = path.resolve('images/',  `${title}.jpg`)
      console.log(Path)
      const writer = fs.createWriteStream(Path)

      axios({
        url: URL,
        method: 'GET',
        responseType: 'stream'
      })
      .then((response) => {
        response.data.pipe(writer)
      })

    }
```

On running this function when downloading, the console gives the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined
    at isURLSameOrigin (isURLSameOrigin.js?3934:57)
    at dispatchXhrRequest (xhr.js?b50d:109)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at xhrAdapter (xhr.js?b50d:12)
    at dispatchRequest (dispatchRequest.js?5270:52)
```

What might cause this?

Comment: Can you check if `URL` is defined right before the `axios({...})`?

Comment: `console.log(URL)` just before the `axios` call prints `https://preview.redd.it/x3sx89sclqm41.png?auto=webp&s=a9b52a922794a8250e82ae02b5393cea9573f47a` which I can copy paste on a browser and it works fine

Comment: Are you using `Vue.use(axios)`?

Comment: No. I've installed it using npm and am simply importing it.

Comment: After looking at [axios source code](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/lib/helpers/isURLSameOrigin.js#L47) I think there might be an issue with `originURL`. Could you check the values of `originURL` and `parsed` [here](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/lib/helpers/isURLSameOrigin.js#L57)?

Comment: I looked around some more and seems like the problem is not with axios but rather Electron itself. You can only download from the main renderer process. So I needed to use ipcRenderer to pass the url to main process where it parsed it and downloaded it. There is a library called `electron-dl` for that so I used that.